# AngularJS Bootstrap accordion with is-open as true

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get my accordions to be open by default, so I set up my controller like this:

```
self.groups = configuratorService.groupGarmentsByCollection(garments);
self.status = {
    open: true
};
```

and then in my HTML I have this:

```
{{ garmentController.status }}

<div accordion>
    <div ng-repeat="group in garmentController.groups" accordion-group is-open="garmentController.status.open">
        <div accordion-heading>
            {{ group.label }} ({{ group.garments.length }}) <span class="pull-right fa" ng-class="{ 'fa-chevron-down': garmentController.status.open, 'fa-chevron-right': !garmentController.status.open } "></span>
        </div>

        <div class="picker garment-picker row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="garment in group.garments">
                        <a class="thumbnail" href="" ng-class="{ 'active': garmentController.matchGarment(garment) }" ng-click="garmentController.setGarment(garment)">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <p>{{ garment.title }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason when I run this, the status output at the top shows **{ "open": false }** and when I click the accordion header, nothing happens.
Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Comment: What version of angularjs are you using? Why are you setting the values on the controller itself rather than the scope?

Comment: hmm, do you not use controllerAs? The values are being set on the scope. I am using 1.3.15

Comment: I do use controllers but I haven't ever accessed the scope the way you are in your html template. I've not set attributes on the controller itself but rather on the injected scope provided by the framework. Perhaps you just haven't provided enough code to present the full picture of what you have done.

Comment: not "do you use controllers", I mean do you use "controllerAs". Anyway, yeah I think that is what you are missing.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but still don't have enough code context to help answer the question because there are still instances where the explicit $scope is necessary, not simply the controller as an object bound to the $scope. Furthermore, there can be interesting quirks related to treating the controller as an instanced object.